# RDP Sessions disconnect only on a few machines

Tags: windows-7, rdp, service

I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light, I have a server 2012 terminal server and 10 windows 7 clients. All work fine apart from 2. When in the session they will disconnect and then reconnect - it always seems to happen at the same workflow. The only significant difference on these two is the RDP client being 8.1. This said, I have been unable to replicate from a another machine with the same client.

It is not profile related as I have had users test that work no problem on the problematic machines, same effect. I have upgraded network drivers to no avail and also plugged the machines direct into the router - the same problem persists. I am not sure which other angles there are to take, if the other machines didnt work perfectly it would lead me to a single issue, but the mis-match of only two affected is leaving me drawing blanks.

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!